# Optimizing my KnockOutJS function - From Ugly Code to Clean, How?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

### Function Description

This function is supposed to simply replace an item in my observable array.

**I am accepting 3 parameters:**

1. findBy = Whether to locate the source index by "id" or "name" property.
2. cmpVal = The value we are searching the array for
3. objNewItem = The new item. This case ex, { id: "12" , name: "NewName" }

Then I am deleting that index from the array, and finally pushing the new object into the array.

I had no luck using the replace function from Knockout, so I had to write my own.

I realize this may be the ugliest code on the internet. That's why I am deferring to you professionals here. :)

```
/* Update A Station 
  *
  *  @param   findBy      string    Property to find ( "id" or "name")
  *  @param   cmpVal      string    Value to compare against
  *  @param   objNewItem  object    The new object replacing old
  * */
  self.modifyStation = function(findBy, cmpVal, objNewItem){

    var sourceIndex;
    var oldId;

    /* Find Index Of Old Station */
    var c = -1;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.station(), function(item) {
      c++;
      switch (findBy) {

        case "id":
          var value = item.id();
          if(value == cmpVal){
            sourceIndex = c;
            oldId = item.id();
          }
          break;

        case "name":
          var value = item.name();
          if(value == cmpVal){
            sourceIndex = c;
            oldId = item.id();
          }
          break;
      }

    });

    /* Remove Old */
    self.station().splice(sourceIndex,1);

    /* Insert New Station 
    *  [For Now] not allowing updating of ID. Only
    *  can update the other properties (yes, I realize that
    *  only leaves "name", but more will be added )
    */
    objNewItem.id = oldId;  // Put old ID back in
    self.station.push(objNewItem);

  }
```

**Note:** *I am not allowing them to edit the ID for now.*

Can anyone help me clean this up? I am smart enough to know its not efficient, but I don't know how else to optimize it.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so...

First of we will create a function that will contain all the logic, from this example on you can do anything with it. The most proper way would be to extend your 'observableArray' directly on [knockout](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html), but i am not going to get this one this far now :P

```
function ReplaceInObservableArray(obsArray, prop, cmpVal, newItem){
    // use the fact that you can get the value of the property by treating the object as the dictionary that it is
  // so you do not need to program for specific properties for different array model types
    var foundItems = obsArray().filter(function(i){ 

        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(i[prop]) == cmpVal;
    });

    if(foundItems.length > 1) 
    {
      // handle what happens when the property you are comparing is not unique on your list. More than one items exists with this comparison run
      // you should throw or improve this sample further with this case implementation.
    } else if(foundItems.length == 0) 
    {
        // handle what happens when there is nothing found with what you are searching with.
    } else {
        // replace at the same index rather than pushing, so you dont move any other items on the array
        // use the frameworks built in method to make the replacement
        obsArray.replace(foundItems[0], newItem);
    }
}

var demoArray = ko.observableArray([{ id : 1, name : 'test1' },{id : 2, name : 'test2' },{ id : 3, name : 'test3'},{id : 4, name : 'test4'}]);
ReplaceInObservableArray(demoArray,'id', 1, {id : 1, name : 'test111'});
ReplaceInObservableArray(demoArray,'name', 'test3', {id : 3, name : 'test3333'});
console.log(demoArray());
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, @MKougiouris !! I can see how that really does make this more versatile. A++ answer.